# What goes where in the Java Memory model for the following example?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

```
class MyClass{
   public void method(){
     String s = new String("a");
   }
}
```

- s goes to JVM Stack
- new String("a") goes to Heap
- "a" goes to SCP. Which is in Metaspace.

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  The key point to remember is that non-primitive variables always store references, which are either null or point to an object.  That object is either in the heap or in metaspace.  In the case of a local variable, the reference itself is on the stack.  So when you say "s goes to JVM stack", what you mean is that the reference that s contains is on the stack, but the object that it refers to is on the heap.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem That part is not clear to me. "That object is either in the heap or in metaspace." Metaspace does _not_ contain objects. So there are 2 copies of "a" one as an object on the heap and another as a string literal in Metaspace, right?

Comment: The literal "a" will be created in the Heap. Starting from Java 7, the String Pool is moved inside the heap. SCP doesn't reside in the Metaspace.

Comment: @null "Since the Method Area contains artifacts “such as the run-time constant pool, field and method data, and the code for methods and constructors…”, in other words non-Java-objects (the pool may contain references to heap objects though), it is part of the Metaspace now." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163218/is-method-area-still-present-in-java-8